# Binding Variable Value with String Interpolation Error with Angular 4, Ionic and Cloudinary

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, cloudinary, angular5

I am using ionic 3, angular 4, Cloudinary to build an image editing application. I am trying to display an image and apply an overlay transformation, however when trying to bind a variable value to the overlays public_ID I get an error: "Can't bind to 'overlay' since it isn't a known property of 'cl-transformation'." To isolate the issue I assigned the variable a fixed value of a correct public ID, yet it still does not work. Please take a look at the code below which shows a working example and the non working example.

```html
//Works perfectly fine

<cl-image public-id="sample.jpg" >
  <cl-transformation overlay="testOverlay" height= "400">
  </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

```js
export class ImagesPage {

overlayID: string = "testOverlay";
```

```html
//Throws error

<cl-image public-id="sample.jpg" >
  <cl-transformation overlay="{{overlayID}}" height= "400">
  </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

Comment: Did you try this style of syntax: `[overlay]="overlayID"`

Comment: Yea did try that one, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use attribute value :

```
[attr.overlay]="overlayID"
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, you can check it as correct if it helped

Comment: `[attr.overlay]="overlayID"`would be the proper way to do it, since string interpolation is not recommended for attribute binding :)